# How to associate each token in a set with a set of tokens in C++

Tags: c++, string, set, token

I have a set of tokens declared as such:

```
std::set<std::string> tokens;
```

To which I `insert` a number of ordered token strings. Now I need to associate each token in the set with another unique set of string tokens. In C I would just be keeping an array of tokens and an array of arrays of tokens, which would share the same first dimension index. What I'm wondering is what the "C++ version" of this type of data structure is and how it's implemented.

```
tokens = {"list1", "list2"}
sets = {"list1": {"item1", "item2", "item3"}, "list2": {"item1", "item2"}}
```

is pretty much what I'm going for, the end-goal is to perform set operations on tokens taken from std input.

Comment: You `push_back` into a `std::set`??

Comment: Oops, got mixed up with vectors. Yes, I meant insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `std::map` for this.

```
std::map<std::string, std::set<std::string>> tokens;
tokens["list1"].insert("item1");
tokens["list1"].insert("item2");
tokens["list1"].insert("item3");
tokens["list2"].insert("item1");
tokens["list2"].insert("item2");
// etc
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response, thought I had already accepted your answer. std::map is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be using an std::multimap instead of a set.
This will guarantee that each "key" appears once, and that each "value" appears at most once per key although the same value could appear for multiple keys.

Comment: Forgot to come back to this until today, I just wanted to point out that I found std::multimap allows duplicate keys, while std::map enforces uniqueness of the keys.